# Calculating Joules from pedaling a bicycle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, software

I have a software issue I am trying to tackle.

I need to calculate the joules done by pedaling a bycicle one full rotation of the pedals.  The way that I am currently doing is this:

1. F - I have force sensors on the two bicycle pedals that tell me how much force the foot is pushing the pedal.  So in one rotation I might get 20 readings.  I am taking the average of those readings to get the force per rotation.
2. D - I know the distance the pedals are traveling in one rotation, which is the circumference of the circular path

Then I am using the equation W = F * D to calculate the total energy or work in one rotation.

I then take the joules and convert to calories, but my numbers seem too high.  Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: What do you consider "too high" here? Can you show your results?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are calories (4.2 J) typically used in thermal calculations and Calories (4200 J) like you would see on food wrappers.  Perhaps that's the source of your surprisingly high calorie value.

Comment: Yeah, this is the reason I asked him to show some results.

Comment: @M. Enns Yes thank you.  I was using gram calories, so I need to divide Joules by 4184 to get the kilocalories found on food wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be a useful approach to consider.  I believe you need to take into account the torque produced rather than just the force directly.  The torque is given by:

$$
\tau = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} = rF \sin \theta
$$

where $r$ is the pedal length, $F$ is the force, which presumably is a function of the angle $\theta$ that the pedal crank makes with the vertical - please see figure below for the geometry.

To compute the work done by the torque, this is given by:

$$
W=\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\tau \mathrm{d} \theta
$$

Then, taking $\theta_{1}=0, \theta_{2}=\pi$ and multiplying by two, assuming that force is only applied on the downward portion of each side and we are pushing down with both legs:

$$
W = 2\int_{0}^{\pi} r \sin \theta F\left(\theta\right) \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

$$
W = 2 r\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin \theta F\left(\theta\right) \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

If the force is about the same at all points on the downward push, we can assume the average as a first approximation (although presumably this can be improved if the crank angle is known for each force measurement).  We then have:

$$
W = 2 r F_{avg} \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin \theta  \mathrm{d}\theta = 2 r F_{avg} \left [ -\cos\theta \right ]_{0}^{\pi} = 4 r F_{avg}
$$

Note that his result is less than what one would compute based on the circumference distance of the pedal movement which is:

$$
d=2 \pi r \approx 6.28 r
$$

which would be higher by a factor of $6.28/4=1.57$.

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This calculates the work being applied to the components of the bicycle, right?  It is less than the work or energy being exerted by the person.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are trying to calculate the useful work done on the bicycle, rather than the energy used by the cyclist.

Whilst one pedal is doing work in the direction of rotation, work is being done against the other pedal. (I assume that the force is always applied downwards.) So it is not the average force on both pedals which you need to use, but the average **difference** in forces between the two pedals.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the energy used by the cyclist